# How do CDs and similar devices nullify the color of the light shined on it?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics

I read that the light that is shined on the cd is the same wavelength as double the hole of the disk. This causes the projected and reflected light to be perfectly out of phase such that the sum of the two waves cancels each other out.

But from what I know, there is no way to physically alter electromagnetic radiation without it being either completely or partially absorbed by a medium.

So when the light is canceled, is it a property of the reflective surface or some other principle of electromagnetic radiation that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you have destructive interference like this, you have constructive interference in a different direction. So, the electromagnetic energy doesn't reach the detector, but goes elsewhere. I'm not familiar enough with the details to know exactly where in this case.